# Devise using user ID as format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Below is how my form is declared in Devise:

`<%= form_for @user, as: :user, url: user_registration_path(@user), remote: true do |f| %>`

It is set up using this syntax in my `routes.rb` file:

`devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }`

Also, my routes are listed as this using `rake routes`:

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                  users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                         users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                 users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                    users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                         users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                         users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                         users/registrations#destroy
```

If I do `user_registration_path` it works, but this isn't sending the user straight from the form, which doesn't line up with how Devise says it should work (`user_registration_path(@user)`)

The problem with the way I'm doing it, is the user's ID gets registered as the format (`/users(.:id)` basically), so it looks like `/users.3`. I understand this is because the :id isn't declared in the route, but it's supposed to be, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<%= form_for @user, as: :user, url: user_registration_path(@user), remote: true do |f| %>
```

With

```
<%= form_for @user, as: :user, url: registration_path(@user), remote: true do |f| %>
```